# Drag and Drop JavaFX using FXML layout

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, fxml, scenebuilder

Drag and Drop  javafx fxml layout

I am trying to reproduce my website accountingsnapshots.com   In Chapter 2 I use drag and drop with HTML and Javascript. (on the link below please go to third screen).

http://accountingsnapshots.com/chapter2/02-inter-deb-exer2-1.php#topMenu

Drag "Cash" to the top box and "Capital" to the bottom box. Three buttons

1. Check the answer and give feedback
2. A "Tell me"  button and
3. a "Show transaction" button.

In JavaFX with FXML I have the drag and drop substituted with radio buttons.  I would prefer to use drag and drop.

Could you point me to an example that shows drag and drop using JavaFX FXML layout.

Comment: Try and go through [`Drag-and-Drop Feature in JavaFX Applications`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm). It has a complete [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/HelloDragAndDrop.java.html). You can assign the methods to listeners from fxml, using scene builder.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, I have looked through and tried many examples without success.  Most require huge amounts of code with tiny results.  I am still trying to produce an acceptable result.